# IBM watson assistant export logs

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I used the script below to export logs from watson successfully a few weeks ago. However, I couldn't use the same script to export logs in the past few days.

I received error message "no logs found" after sending the request.

May I know if anyone also encounter this problem?

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/community/commit/b91891c5379ecc62b1ddcded34f6e4a1d58d6e1c

Comment: Do you mean this script? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/community/blob/master/watson-assistant/export_logs_py.py What was the error? Add more details to your question

Comment: Yes, i was using this script. I got error of "no logs found" but i am sure that there are conversation history in my chatbot. @data_henrik

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a result like "no logs found" and no error message, then it seems ok. [Depending on your service plan of IBM Watson Assistant there are different limits how long logs are retained](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-logs#logs-limit). Thus, you might have received logs when checking first, but when checking again some days later with no new activities there might be no log data anymore to return.

The [API docs for Watson Assistant have details on list log events](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2#listlogs) and have code samples for Python, Node.js, Java, Go and more languages. Check that your script follows that Python example.

Comment: I checked and confirmed there are only fewer than 10 conversations from the "analytics --> user conversation" page in the ibm watson webpage. It is strange that I still receive error message of no logs found with the python script.

Comment: Add more details to your question. How did you invoke the script? Do the workspace ID and account match?